# SSAS calculated measure with where clause (MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, business-intelligence, cube

I am trying to create a calculated measure to calculate average with something like a where clause in VS2012 BI.

CREATE MEMEBR CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sem Average]

AS [Measures].[SG_Sem] / [Measures].[Counted_Rows] **<-This is already working**

WHERE [Measures][Kenn] = 'BE' **<-something like this is missing**

THX

Comment: The WHERE clause defines the slicer axis and Measures.[Kenn] is an aggregated value. There should be a dimensional attribute. This query makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sem Average]

AS 
  ( 
     ([Measures].[SG_Sem] / [Measures].[Counted_Rows]) , [Measures][Kenn].&[BE] )
  )
```